# Vectorize for cell array assignment: How to avoid multiple for loop or nested for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, vectorization

In MATLAB, I have `c` being a large sparse matrix computed before and want to assign value to cell array `D` by using the outer product of `c` columns. However, I have to implemented special rules and cannot get outer product of same `c` columns.

Start from column 1 using the first for loop, I have to implemented another for loop and an if-else statement (for "flagging" as I increase the index in the second for loop) to avoid outer product of same `c` columns.

Eventually, after the nested for loop, I want to add up all the `D` to get a matrix `K`. This is my very first version and the idea behind:

```
c = rand(100,100);    
D = cell(1,100);
D{1} = eye(100);
for i = 1:100
        flag = false;
        for z = 2 :100
            j = z-1;
            if j == i
               flag = true;
            end 
            if flag == true
               D{z} = (c(:,j+1)*c(:,i)');
            else 
               D{z} = (c(:,j)*c(:,i)');
            end
        end
         for z = 2 : 100
             K = K + D{z}';
         end
end
```

I know how to remove the nested loop, but in turns I still need multiple for loops on the first layer and the performance is not too strong. I have been thinking about using `NDGRID` or `bsxfun` to do this but to no avail.

Comment: could you please add an example for `c`?

Comment: @Finn `c` is a 100 by 100 matrix..It is computed elsewhere where columns are eigenvectors from another matrix. It has no special structure.  (It can be `rand(100,100)`)

Comment: could you please give a little more detail about this: you have a 100x100 matrix and want to create 100 100x100 matrizes from that. And in the end you want the sum of those 100 matrizes. And in total you want the sum of the products of each colum multiplied with every other colum, and instead of it self the next one twice. is that correct?

Comment: @Finn just omitting itself, the outer product is done once. Therefore the addition is 99 times inside one loop. I figure how to do this without the nested loop. But still not every well-performed. Any function like `bsxfun` or even without the first loop is really appreciated.

Comment: in what range are the values of c?i may have a way, but its tricky if you multiply 99 values and some are e^10 and some e^-10 there might get rounding error due to double precision

Comment: @Finn the values of `c` not really fixed. but too large or too small values may be rare. (they should normally be in order of e^-1 to e^-5).

Comment: @Finn `K` in the above can be initialized to matrix of 0 entries.

Answer (score 0):

ok i got something; you check which vectors to take, then create 99 products and then sum those up. i would get the 99 vectors, sum those up and then create the product, as a*b+a*c=a*(b+c). in your code this would make:

```
c=rand(100,100);
D = cell(1,100);
D{1} = eye(100);
K=zeros(100);
tic
for i = 1:100
        flag = false;
        for z = 2 :100
            j = z-1;
            if j == i
               flag = true;
               FLAGMATRIX(i,j)=true;
            end 
            if flag == true
               D{z} = (c(:,j+1)*c(:,i)');
            else 
               D{z} = (c(:,j)*c(:,i)');
            end
        end
         for z = 2 : 100
             K = K + D{z}';
         end
end
toc
Matrix=zeros(100);
tic
for i=1:100
    %creating 1:100 the vector w/o i
    vector=1:100;
    vector(i)=[];
    %sum up the 2nd dimension
    sumvec=sum(c(:,vector),2);
    Matrix=[Matrix + c(:,i)*sumvec'];
end
toc
```

you can make it even shorter in the code but this wont change the performance

```
Matrix2=zeros(100);
tic
for i=1:100
    sumvec=sum(c(:,[1:i-1 i+1:100]),2);%vector creation + sum
    Matrix2=[Matrix2 + c(:,i)*sumvec'];
end
toc
```

which on my machine performs

```
Elapsed time is 0.527004 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.006401 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.007078 seconds.
```

this is probably of no importance but there is a difference between your and my results in the e-13 department. Yet i would argue that mine would be closer to reality if the numbers come from about the same range as the summing up wont harm there calcualting the product has to be done somewhere anyway